# Viber aborts unexpectedly while launching

Tags: viber

Just installed Viber on a 64-bit ubuntu 14.10, but launching it from the menu or the `.desktop` file didn't work; launching from the terminal either with sudo-rights or not results with a message "Aborted"; a quick shot from gdb results :

```
 Starting program: /opt/viber/Viber 
Cannot exec /opt/viber/Viber -c exec /opt/viber/Viber .
Error: No such file or directory
During startup program exited with code 127.
```

Despite all of it, `file /opt/viber/Viber` results in `/opt/viber/Viber: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=27413a56e406a81595a30b69d35ba4e3ebfb0760, not stripped`

All shared libs are satisfied too by using `ldd /opt/viber/Viber`:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8ddef000)
    libqfacebook.so => /opt/viber/libqfacebook.so (0x00007f3e43f02000)
    libXss.so.1 => /opt/viber/libXss.so.1 (0x00007f3e43cfd000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3e43adb000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f3e432be000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f3e42f58000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f3e42d17000)
    libQt5WebKit.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5WebKit.so.5 (0x00007f3e40823000)
    libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5 (0x00007f3e405df000)
    libQt5Declarative.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Declarative.so.5 (0x00007f3e4004c000)
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007f3e3fdc8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3e3fbc3000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3e3f9bb000)
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x00007f3e3f761000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f3e3f03e000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f3e3e920000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3e3e611000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3e3e30a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3e3e0f4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3e3dd2f000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f3e3d9f5000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f3e3d7e3000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3e3d5c8000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f3e3d32b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3e44128000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f3e3d121000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f3e3cf1d000)
    libicui18n.so.48 => /opt/viber/libicui18n.so.48 (0x00007f3e3cb55000)
    libicuuc.so.48 => /opt/viber/libicuuc.so.48 (0x00007f3e3c7eb000)
    libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007f3e3c5ad000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f3e3c1e4000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3e3bed5000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3e3bc82000)
    libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f3e3b998000)
    libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f3e3b78b000)
    libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f3e3b536000)
    libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f3e3b324000)
    libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f3e3b100000)
    libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00007f3e3aee2000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f3e3ac1b000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Quick.so.5 (0x00007f3e3a666000)
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007f3e3a051000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007f3e39ded000)
    libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5XmlPatterns.so.5 (0x00007f3e397ac000)
    libQt5Script.so.5 => /opt/viber/libQt5Script.so.5 (0x00007f3e3932f000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f3e3910f000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f3e38ee6000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f3e38cbc000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f3e38ab8000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f3e388b2000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f3e386b0000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f3e38498000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f3e38293000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f3e38090000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f3e37e8c000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f3e37c86000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f3e37a84000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f3e3787d000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f3e37671000)
    libicudata.so.48 => /opt/viber/libicudata.so.48 (0x00007f3e36300000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007f3e35f82000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f3e35d15000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f3e35b0c000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3e35908000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f3e35683000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f3e3547f000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f3e35278000)
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007f3e33a0b000)
```

Lastly, I tried turning it on and off but nothing about this changes.

What could be the problem?

UPDATE 1: full gdb result

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.8.2-0ubuntu1) 7.8.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) file /opt/viber/Viber 
Reading symbols from /opt/viber/Viber...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /opt/viber/Viber 
Cannot exec /opt/viber/Viber -c exec /opt/viber/Viber .
Error: No such file or directory
During startup program exited with code 127.
(gdb) backtrace
No stack.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Run `gdb ./Viber` in /opt/viber, then `run` and after it crashes, `backtrace`, edit question and post output here.

Comment: @M132 running `backtrace` only results "No stack."

Comment: Could you post full gdb output? Does Viber actually run, or does gdb just display No such file or directory, just like in the question?

Comment: It just results what ever was shown in the question, and no it does not run.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that issue by specifying `/opt/viber/` in `Path` variable inside `/usr/share/applications/viber.desktop` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the `qt5` module to get it to work:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```